# Combine minted and tcolorbox for code from file (inputminted?)

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, minted

Thanks to [Thomas F. Sturm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124688/15907) and [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125006/cross-referencing-tcolorbox-with-cleveref-package) I have a nice looking environment for code listings with appropriate ref functionalities. However, I just cannot figure out a way to make the defined *listingsbox* use a file. I know this this normally works with `\inputminted` but I do not know how to acieve the same with these special environments.

Any ideas would be gladly apreciated, thanks :-)

Edit: I haven't provided a MWE, I'm stuck at exactly [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125006/cross-referencing-tcolorbox-with-cleveref-package/125029#125029) and I fail to edit it to use `\tcbinputlisting` :-(

Comment: Well, could you please post a version of your document or shall we glue the examples of T.F Sturm and Gonzalo Medina together? Is `tcbinputlisting` not working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I've looked at this question for some hours, checking the `tcolorbox` and `cleveref` documentation (I even asked here for something related to this, although the MWE I initially did was a mess and I deleted the question afterwards), but @cfr gave me clues and finally I found a solution to your problem.

You can create and use your own counters, and the `tcolorbox` package can use them by giving their names when creating the box structure (see the commands `\newtcolorbox`, `\newtcbinputlisting` and `\newtcblisting` in pasted file `mwe.tex`). *Inside* the box, e.g. the `title` property, you have to use `\thetcbcounter` to retreive the value of the counter you've just linked. And regarding cross-referencing, `\crefname` is your best friend (see those commands in the given `mwe.tex` file).

For more information, check the `tcolorbox` and `cleveref` documentation.

Here is the working solution (file `mwe.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{commentCount}
\newcounter{filePrg}
\newcounter{inputPrg}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=letterpaper,margin=2cm}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{\CeX}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcommand{\TwoSymbolsAndText}[3]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c\CeX c}%
    #1 & #2 & #3
  \end{tabularx}%
}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=commentCount, number format=\arabic]{commentBox}[2]{
  size=title,
  arc=1.5mm,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colframe=Black,
  coltitle=White,
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  colback=White,
  coltext=Black,
  title=\TwoSymbolsAndText{\faCheck}{%
    \textbf{Comment \thetcbcounter}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\textbf{:} \textit{#1}}%
  }{\faCheck},
  label=comment:#2,
}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=filePrg, number format=\arabic]{\codeFromFile}[4]{%
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=#1,
  listing file={#2},
  minted options={autogobble,linenos,breaklines},
  listing only,
  size=title,
  arc=1.5mm,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colframe=brown,
  coltitle=White,
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  colback=white,
  coltext=Black,
  title=\TwoSymbolsAndText{\faCode}{%
    \textbf{File program \thetcbcounter}\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\textbf{:} \textit{#3}}%
  }{\faCode},
  label=filePrg:#4
}

\newtcblisting[use counter=inputPrg, number format=\arabic]{codeInput}[3]{
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=#1,
  minted options={autogobble,linenos,breaklines},
  listing only,
  size=title,
  arc=1.5mm,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colframe=brown,
  coltitle=White,
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  colback=white,
  coltext=Black,
  title=\TwoSymbolsAndText{\faCode}{%
    \textbf{Input program \thetcbcounter}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\textbf{:} \textit{#2}}%
  }{\faCode},
  label=inputPrg:#3
}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{commentCount}{comment}{comments}
\crefname{filePrg}{file program}{file programs}
\crefname{inputPrg}{input program}{input programs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{commentBox}{My first comment}{first}
    My first comment here! \faTree
  \end{commentBox}

  \begin{codeInput}{c}{A welcome program.}{code01}
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
      printf("Hello world!\n");
      return 0;
    }
  \end{codeInput}

  \codeFromFile{java}{HelloWorld.java}{Another welcome program.}{code01}

  See \cref{comment:first} for details. Also, look for \cref{inputPrg:code01} and \cref{filePrg:code01} for further assistance.
\end{document}
```

This is the `HelloWorld.java` file used by `mwe.tex` (if you're running this example, make sure to have this file in the same folder of `mwe.tex`):

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
  }
}
```

I compiled it using `latexmk -xelatex -shell-escape mwe.tex`.

And here is the output of the compiling process:

[image: Output of compiling file mwe.tex]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, good - you found it! I looked for your question again, but couldn't find it ;).

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I deleted it because I just copied from another LaTeX file (in fact I had the same problem as the OP), and realized I didn't include many important commands, so the MWE wouldn't have run :(

Comment: No problem. You found the bit anyway!

Comment: Thanks so much, this solution is great :-)

However, while I was customizing it, I noticed that I am not able to build a list of listings. In the solution I posted a simple `\tcblistof{mypyg}{My Listings}` was enough for that because of the `list inside=mypyg` argument of the `\newtcolorbox`. I cannot simply use the counter, i.e. `\tcblistof{filePrg}{My Listings}`, to get such a list. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sickboy Well, the counter was to demostrate the customization you can have. Have you tried with `auto counter` on the options (instead of `use counter=`)? Also, `label type` can help you to include the codes in the listings list, but make sure you have `cleveref` loaded and using already known types, such as `theorem`, `algorithm`, `listing`, etc. It should be interesting if one could make a table of personalized elements made from tcolorboxes, though :)

Comment: @Sickboy I've just read your answer. Good job! I'm glad that can be possible and very happy you found my approach useful! :)

Comment: I have one question for you regarding the ```\codeFromFile``` input, how would you shift the code inside the box with the numbers inside?

Answer (score 2):

So, I figured the `\tcblistof` thing out. It was the title with an image causing the problem. There are two approaches to this issues:

1. Do not use this image in the title definition, but in an overlay. This keeps the title simple and suitable for the list of listings.
2. Use a `list entry` to define a title for the list of listings.

Here's the solution suited to my needs (and shortened). Tanks so much to JBFWP286 again! :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{filePrg}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=letterpaper,margin=2cm}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=filePrg, number within=section, list inside=mypyg]{\codeFromFile}[4]{%
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=#1,
  listing file={#2},
  minted options={autogobble,linenos,breaklines},
  listing only,
  size=title,
    drop fuzzy shadow,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
    %arc=1.5mm,
  %colframe=brown,
  %coltitle=White,
  %boxrule=0.5mm,
  %colback=white,
  %coltext=Black,
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter : #3 \hfill%
    \smash{\raisebox{-11pt}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{images/code2.png}}}},
    list entry=Listing~\thetcbcounter : #3,
    %OR next two lines
    %title={Listing \thetcbcounter : #3},
    %overlay={\node[anchor=north east,outer sep=-9pt] at ([xshift=-25pt]frame.north east) {\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{images/code2.png}}; },
  label=lst:#4
}

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217489/numbering-tcolorbox-toc
\makeatletter % no indent for entries
\renewcommand{\l@tcolorbox}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefname{filePrg}{Listing}{Listings}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\codeFromFile{java}{listings/HelloWorld.java}{Another welcome program.}{code01}

See \cref{lst:code01} for details.

\tcblistof{mypyg}{My Listings}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the problem of too long titles and my solution just went out off the box. So I reconsidered JBFWP286's answer and tweaked it here and there (I obviously changed the style of my boxes as well). Here's a MWE of it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{\LeX}{>{\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcommand{\OneSymbolAndText}[2]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{340pt}{l\LeX}%should normally be \textwidth instead of 340pt but fills out the box nicer this way
    #1 & #2
  \end{tabularx}%
}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{Information}[4][]{%
  breakable,
  enhanced,
    arc=0mm,
    colback=gray,
    colframe=gray,
    borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{blue}, % straigh vertical line at the left edge
    sharp corners, % No rounded corners
    boxrule=0pt, % no real frame,
    size=title,
    bottom=6pt,
    leftupper=12pt,
    lefttitle=35pt,
    toptitle=6pt,
    top=4pt,
    list entry=Information~\thetcbcounter : #1,
    %fonttitle=\scshape,
    fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
    coltitle={black},  % Black colour for title
    title=\hspace{-36pt}\OneSymbolAndText{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{boximages/infoBulle/info}}{%
    \vspace{#4}Information \thetcbcounter : #2},
    #1,
    label=info:#3
}

\usepackage[ngerman,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{tcb@cnt@Information}{Information}{Informationen}
\Crefname{tcb@cnt@Information}{Information}{Informationen}

\begin{document}
\begin{Information}{Really really really I mean really long loooooong Title}{labelInf}{-27.5pt}
Test123
\end{Information}
siehe \cref{info:labelInf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the prior answers here, I would like to add a more general MWE.
Utilizing the `all` option, `tcolorbox` automatically loads `minted`.

Furthermore you can set you global `minted` settings as usual with `\setminted`.

With the following `\codeFromFile` command, you can additionally override the `minted` and `tcolorbox` settings by individual settings via

> `\codeFromFile([minted settings]){language}{file}{Title}{label}{additional tcolorbox settings}`

```
\documentclass[paper=letter]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

% Arbitrary minted settings
\setminted[latex]{
  autogobble,
  fontsize=\scriptsize,
  linenos=true,
  breaklines}

% Arbitrary tcolorbox settings
\tcbset{
 list entry=Listing : #4,
 fonttitle=\bfseries,
 size=fbox,
 arc=1mm,
 colback=white}

\newtcbinputlisting[list inside=mypyg]{\codeFromFile}[6][]{%
  listing engine=minted,
  minted options={#1},
  minted language=#2,
  listing file={#3},
  title={\centering #4},
  label=#5,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  #6
}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%
\codeFromFile[fontsize=\large]{latex}{minimal.tex}{Program}{code01}{width=10cm,colframe=red!75!black}
\codeFromFile{latex}{minimal.tex}{Another program}{code02}{}
%
\tcblistof{mypyg}{My Listings}
%
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered image]

P.s.: I found no (working) way to include a second optional argument for the tcb settings. Afaik you need to redefine `\newtcbinputlisting` using e.g. [`xparse`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse)'s `\DeclareDocumentCommand`... Hence just append a `{}` if you don't hand over additional `tcolorbox` settings (see "Another brogram" box).