# Add title bar to minted code display

Tags: minted, python

I would like to know how to go about adding a title bar to a `minted` block of python code?  This is an example of a title bar I would like to use:

[image]

I tried using the code from [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304449/combine-minted-and-tcolorbox-for-code-from-file-inputminted) but I could not get the code posted in that solution to compile using WinEdt with the `pdftex` `-shell-escape`.  When I run the code from the posted [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304449/combine-minted-and-tcolorbox-for-code-from-file-inputminted), I get this error:

> Error: cannot read infile: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'codeboxes_1.pyg'

> ! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
> probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need
> the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
> or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

Here is my code thus far:

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[letter, 12pt]{report}   

%###########################         FOR PYTHON         ####################################
% https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor} % to access the named colour LightGray
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
bgcolor=LightGray,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
firstnumber = 41,
linenos
]
{python}
fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,2))
ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(times, x)
ax.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('amplitude [in A.U.]', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('time [in sec]', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(fontsize=13)
plt.yticks(fontsize=13)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to see how the code you posted could generate the error message you posted — or did you get that when trying out the code in the linked solution? It looks like you were trying to input code from a file and didn't have that file present.

The actual code you posted compiles for me, but does not have the title bar; for that you need the tcolorbox package.

Below is an attempt to modify the code in the solution you linked to to use for your python code. I didn't bother with the other environments defined in that solution: just the environment that generates code blocks that looks like your desired output.

I added a fourth argument for the starting line number to the code given there.

However, it's still fairly different from the style of the code you posted: are there tweaks you want to make?

```
\documentclass[letter, 12pt]{report}

\newcounter{commentCount}
\newcounter{filePrg}
\newcounter{inputPrg}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{\CeX}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcommand{\TwoSymbolsAndText}[3]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c\CeX c}%
    #1 & #2 & #3
  \end{tabularx}%
}

\newtcblisting[use counter=inputPrg, number format=\arabic]{codeInput}[4]{
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=#1,
  minted options={autogobble,linenos,breaklines,  firstnumber={#4}},
  listing only,
  size=title,
  arc=1.5mm,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colframe=brown,
  coltitle=White,
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  colback=white,
  coltext=Black,
  title=\TwoSymbolsAndText{\faCode}{%
    \textbf{Input program \thetcbcounter}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\textbf{:} \textit{#2}}%
  }{\faCode},
  label=inputPrg:#3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeInput}{python}{A sample program.}{code01}{41}
fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,2))
ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(times, x)
ax.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('amplitude [in A.U.]', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('time [in sec]', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(fontsize=13)
plt.yticks(fontsize=13)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
\end{codeInput}

\end{document}
```

[image: python with head bar]

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  I mis-wrote those words...my apologies.  My code did not generate the error, it was the code from the link I posted in my question that I generated the error.  I will reformat that sentence properly so that it will reflect what code I meant generated the error.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am getting the same error when I try your code.  Is there a specific library that I am missing that is causing this error?  I'm running Windows 10.  Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say. Can you post your complete log file? Is your TeX distribution up to date? Does pygmentize work from the command line?

Comment: Hello, I got it to work partially by using the command `\RequirePackage[cache=false]{minted}`, however, for the output generated, I just the boxed header with no python code in there.  Let me try if `pygmentize` works from the command line.\

Comment: I get the `Error: cannot read infile: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:` with I run the `pygmentize` from the command line.  Is that why my compilation is failing?

Comment: What is the exact command you're running from the command line? That error looks like you tried to use it on a file that doesn't exist, which wouldn't tell us much about how it's working (or not) with minted.

Comment: You are correct!  I tried it again on a file that did exist this time and it gave a colorful output on the command window.  pygmentize is working from the command prompt.